# Error in layout.js, cart not loading

Tags: magento2, layout

I've got a problem with Magento 2.0.6.

`layout.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: Constr is not a constructor (layout.js line 64)`

The cart is not loading anymore, the minicart-wrapper stays empty. Problem firstly only existed on Safari and iOS, meanwhile (and without any changes - thats where its getting weird) it also stopped working on all other browsers, Firefox, Mac, you name it.

Does anyone else is having this problem?

Comment: Did you run static content deploy and checked ?

Comment: The shop has enabled developer mode. Therefore, no static content deploy is needed in order to deploy files.