# Constr is not a constructor on layout.js line 137 error custom module

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, onestepcheckout, requirejs-config.js

I have gone through this posts and tried to implement the answers and suggestions

[Magento2 getting 'Constr is not a constructor' error for custom theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117007/magento2-getting-constr-is-not-a-constructor-error-for-custom-theme) &&  [Error in layout.js, cart not loading](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128622/error-in-layout-js-cart-not-loading) && [No Way to Clear/delete a Selected Image using Media Browser on category edit page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175251/no-way-to-clear-delete-a-selected-image-using-media-browser-on-category-edit-pag)

But I am not able to resolve this issue .

Here is what I have done -> I am trying to reuse module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js file in my custom module, Here is what I have done so far

This is my registration.js file

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Rahul_Learning',
    __DIR__
);
```

This is Rahul/Learning/etc/module.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Rahul_Learning" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

This is Rahul/Learning/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address': {
                'Rahul_Learning/js/view/billing-address': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and at location Rahul/Learning/view/frontend/web/js/view I have copy pasted  module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js file without any changes but I am getting this error on checkout page

[image]

Looking forward for your suggestions not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid the copy-paste technique as much as possible.

In your `requirejs-config.js` you are declaring that you would like to apply mixins to `Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address` with `Rahul_Learning/js/view/billing-address`.

The original component, i.e. `Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address` when applying mixins, is referred to as the `target`, and inside the component that does the override of the target, you will ALWAYS get A REFERENCE TO THE TARGET.

The code then, in your .js file should be like

```
define([], function(){

    'use strict';

    return function(originalBillingAddress){
        return originalBillingAddress.extend({
            //YOUR NEW CODE GOES HERE
        });
    };
});
```

So, in this example the variable `originalBillingAddress` would be the original object that comes from `Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address` and you `return` AN EXTENSION of it by using the `.extend` function.

I have left the `define([], function(){` as empty, but, as by default RequireJS functionality, you can pass any dependencies here that you like, for example

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
```

this way you load `jQuery` and refer to it later as `$`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much , This seems to be the correct  and better solution .

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this is the correct answer or not but this fix the issue  hope it will help someone so I am posting here .

Made changes to  requirejs-config.js and the error I was facing is gone.

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address":"Rahul_Learning/js/view/billing-address"
        }
    }
};
```