# Constr is not a constructor on layout.js line 137 error

Tags: checkout, customer

This error is shown in my console after when the customer is logged in and by this checkout page is not working without customer logged in checkout page working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered before. It is usually an issue when declaring mixins. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/243004/185 for the solution.

Comment: I have tried this but it didn't work